# java wait for event from thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an application that has a main thread. At point A, I create a child thread that does something. Meanwhile, the main application thread ought not stop.

At point B, the child thread reaches an intermediate solution. It now needs input from the main application thread. How can I achieve this?

I cannot use wait()/notify(), because the main application thread should not be waiting (ie ui events should still be processed). I envision something like this (simplified/pseudocofidied):

Main Thread:

```
public void foo(){
    child = new Thread();
    child.start();
    ...
    return;
}

...


public void receiveEventFromChildProcess(){
    bar();
}
```

Child

```
Public void start(){
    run();
}

Public void run(){
    bla();
    //Intermediate solution reached
    notifyMainApplicationThread();
}
```

Is this feasible? I acknowledge that I may not be approaching this problem correctly at all. Thank you however for our help :)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what input is needed from main thread?

Comment: The main thread is an interface that processes user input. When a user presses a button, a long calculation commences. I would like that, after the calculation is finished, the main waits for a subsequent user input and, once it is given, the child thread resumes calculating.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "the main thread?" Are you talking about a GUI thread? A GUI thread should _always_ be waiting for user input. Every millisecond during which the GUI thread is busy doing something is a millisecond during which your application will be unresponsive. If you allow your GUI thread to be busy for too many milliseconds in a row, it could give users the impression that your application is slow.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `CountDownLatch` to achieve your use case. I am providing an example here.

```
public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

            CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
            Thread worker = new Thread(new Worker(countDownLatch));
            worker.start();
            // do some work in mian
            // now the point reached and you want wait main therad for notification from child therad
            countDownLatch.await(); //main will wait at this ponit still the child thread did not call countDownLatch.countDown();

        }

    }

    class Worker implements Runnable {

        CountDownLatch countDownLatch;

        Worker(CountDownLatch countDownLatch) {
            this.countDownLatch = countDownLatch;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // bla();
            countDownLatch.countDown(); // it will notify the main thread to resume its work
            // notifyMainApplicationThread();
        }
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't work with "(...) the main application thread should not be waiting (ie ui events should still be processed)"

Comment: As per the OP's comment "I would like that, after the calculation is finished, the main waits for a subsequent" the main thread will wait when it needs to user input.

Comment: Also the main therad will keep running still the time you do not call ` countDownLatch.await()` on it.

Comment: But the main doesn't know when to start waiting. It ought to, as soon as the other thread is created, listen to see if it has reached its intermediate state.

Answer (score 0):

Using an executor with callables might help you. Something like:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<MyClass> result = executor.submit(new MyCallable());
```

When you get a result from your child process you can for example pass it to some listener that notifies a main thread.